# ✖ Could not check NPM version "", assuming incompatible

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-forge

I'm facing the above error while running `npm run make`.
forge.config.js :

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    icon: '/icon'
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

package.json scripts :

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "electron .",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
```

Full log can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFJN9.png)

I tried updating npm to the latest version globally, still facing the same issue. Also tried to run `npm run package` instead of make, still didn't work.